# How to use Typescript to restrict React component children to another functional component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Since ReactJS is recommending functional components, I am trying to understand how to use typescript to restrict the children prop to another function component.

```
interface HumanProps {
    children: JSX.Element;
}

const Human = (props: HumanProps) => (
    <>{props.children}</>
)

interface HumanParentProps {
    children: Human[]; // Question: how to declare this in typescript?
}

const HumanParent = (props: HumanParentProps) => (
    <Human> // HumanParent is a Human by composition
        {props.children} // its children must also be Human
    </Human>
)
```

How can I ensure that `HumanParent.children` is of type `Human` as per above snippet?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Children in React are not functions or classes, but what that functions or `render` methods of classes output passed into `createElement` function. Apart from this, you can pass `false`, `null`, `undefined` (not sure about this one, but should work) and strings as children.

What you can do instead, it to set up some ESLint rule (find one, or write it yourself) that will prevent you and your colleagues from creating component classes.